# Upload file fields in same form : one is working, not the other

Tags: forms, symfony, file-upload

I have a form in my symfony2 project.
The form contain 2 file upload fields, that are used depending on a radio button choice made by the user. Depending on this choice, the right file uploaded is copied into the user folder.

My problem is that one of the 2 fields is working (copied) and not the other. It's very strange to me.

I provide some code (i removed some things that might not be necessary).

Here is my entity :

```
class MyEntity
{
    private $file1;
    private $file2;

    /**
     * Set file1 
     */
    public function setFile1($file1)
    {
        $this->file1 = $file1;      
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get file of file1
     *
     */
    public function getFile1()
    {
        return $this->file1;
    }

    /**
     * Set file of file1
     */
    public function setFile2($file2)
    {
        $this->file2 = $file2;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get file of file2
     *
     */
    public function getFile2()
    {
        return $this->file2;
    }
}
```

My entity type :

```
class MyEntitytype extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('file1', 'file', array('required'  => false));
        $builder->add('file2', 'file', array('required'  => false));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
        array(
            'data_class' => 'my\Bundle\Entity\MyEntity',
            'required'  => false
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'myentitytype';
    }
}
```

My part of controller :

```
    $form = $this->createForm(
        new MyEntitytype(),
        new MyEntity()
    );

    // check type is « POST ».
    if( $request->getMethod() == 'POST' )
    {
        // link between request and form = hydratation
        $form->bindRequest($request);

        // validation
        if( true )
        {
            $data = $form->getData();

            // get uploaded files, depending type
            $type = $data->getType();
            if( $type == 'dndd' ){
                $filename = 'filename1';
                $data->getFile1()->move($filepath, $filename);
            }elseif( $type == 'dbscreen') {
                $filename = 'filenam2';
                $data->getFile2()->move($filepath, $filename);
            } else {
                return 'failed';
            }

        }
....
```

Comment: Can you var_dump $data->getFile2() inside your controller ?

Comment: Yes, it returns : /tmp/phpLOXWKO . What does that mean ?

Comment: It's ok, it's the tempopary path of the uploaded file stored in your server, waiting to be moved or deleted. So the file is well uploaded, so I suspect ->move($filepath, $filename); to not work. Are you sure of $filepath ? Did you have all rights (777) to write file inside the folder ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I am sure of filepath and the directory is drwxr-xr-x / 755. I can write in the folder for example with file_put_contents in a controller. What is strange is that in the first case the file is copied and in the other it's not.

Comment: Looks like there was something wrong with the filename. I just changed to another one and it's working. Very strange. Thanks anyway.